# protobuf-net and interface support

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

This question directly in large part to the protobuf-net maintainer(s) but anyone else please comment.

I was trying to serialize a class that contains a property which has an interface type, ie:

```
[DataContract]    
public class SampleDataClass
{
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public int Field1 { get; set; }                

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]        
    public IPayload Payload { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Payload))]
public interface IPayload
{
    int Field4 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Payload : IPayload
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int Field4 { get; set; }
}
```

I have managed to get this to work by changing the source of v1 of protobuf-net. 
I did not see any problem with this approach as long as ProtoInclude is defined for the interface.

Clearly to get this to compile I had to allow ProtoContract and ProtoInclude to be decorated on interfaces, plus a few other changes here and there. (note, I would have used DataContract/KnownType however these attributes are also not able to be decorated on interfaces)

Can you please comment on possible shortcomings?

Comment: This has just been committed to the v2 trunk, btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main glitch I can see is that in terms of payload this moves the data into a sub-message. I have some similar designs around v2 that hopefully get around this, keeping most values in the primary message. For sanity reasons, I mainly had just v2 in mind for this change (since the two implementations would be separate, and v2 has a much better type model).

However, it should be possible to support both modes of use. If you want to send it as a patch for v1 (with the same license etc) I'd happily take a look :)

---

This is available as a standard feature of v2

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you mean by 'this moves the data into a sub-message'.
Is there an issue (performance or other) with an interface nested far down in the object hierarchy?

Comment: @wal - simply, presumably you have (using no particular notation, and changing `Field4`'s tag to 5 for clarity) `{1={len:5=value}}`. I *think* we should aim to support (but not mandate) that the serialization can be on the *interface*, so we have `{1={0},5=value}`, where we still *have* the concrete sub-type, but **unless** it exposes some specific additional data, we serialize at the interface level.

Comment: @mark - I need to look at *known* types (includes) - newly it has mechanism for creating a *default* type (which ties in fairly nicely with something needed for dynamic proxies etc)

Comment: @marc - Currently ProtoInclude is not supported on interfaces (v2). I did not understand from your reply, whether this is by design and thus will stay like this or it is something to be fixed. Sorry for being that slow.

Comment: @mark - it depends on the intent; if the intent is to support known types of interface implementations, then yes: I need to add in known-type support ;p That can be done pretty easily (the v2 type model makes this a breeze); at the moment there is only support for a *default/fallback* implementation, which is a different approach. My only concern is whether (with interface approach) we take members from the interface vs the known type - tricky. But modelling as known-types I guess either should be possible. And yes, that'll involve a change to the attributes.

Comment: @marc: and how do you treat now abstract base type? I do not see much difference between an interface and an abstract base type (except for the multiple inheritance, but that is irrelevant in this context). I would say that you have to take the members of the actual concrete type. An interface may declare the properties read-only, while the concrete type may have the shadow setters - we do not want them in the interface, am I right?

Comment: @mark - that is a design call for you. In the example presented (readonly interface), then it would be most appropriate to declare the storage members at the concrete type, however in cases where the interface is mutable either approach is supported.

Comment: @marc - I see. So, if I understand it correctly you support both ways.